# Grails: Contract first soap web service with cxf is not working

Tags: grails, cxf

Publishing contract first web services in Grails using cxf is not working with the following.
http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=85983334. I could not find any other useful resources on this problem. Using spring-ws may not be a good idea because I don't want to create end points for each element.

Please share some resources if anybody succeeded in publishing web service using cxf in Grails?

Setup:
   Grails 2.0.0
   cxf - 2.4.1
   Grails-cxf - 0.5.1 (Latest is not working)
   Groovy - 1.7.6

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://grails.org/plugin/cxf in several projects. It works great for me. What exactly goes wrong when you try?